# jquery append external html file into my page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append an external html content (div plus some text inside just for testing) this way:

```
$.get("banner.html", function(data){
    $(this).children("div:first").append(data);
});
```

That seems to be pretty simple... but it does not seem to work. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What is your `$(this)`? and you can try `jquery load`, not `get`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use html instead of append:

```
$.get("banner.html", function(data){
    $(this).children("div:first").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 14):

i'm not sure what you're expecting `this` to refer to in your example.. here's an alternative method:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.get("banner.html", function (data) {
                    $("#appendToThis").append(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="appendToThis"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery's load function here.

```
$("#your_element_id").load("file_name.html");
```

If you need more info, [here is the link](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.get("banner.html", function (data) {
                    $("#appendToThis").append(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="appendToThis"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selectors like CSS3

```
$("banner.html>div:first-child").append(data);
```