# jquery .html on an included file

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I have viewed this answer [jquery append external html file into my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page)

And was wondering if it applied to my situation.

I have a page that includes another, can I use the jquery .html() to inject html on the included page?

```
<html><body>some text <includedpage.html></body></html>
```

If includedpage.html contains a div `<div class="demo-container">` Can I inject as such:? `$('div.demo-container')
  .html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>');`

Will this work?

Comment: Yes this should be fine.  This isn't a great question for SO since you could easily test this.  Better to try it and report a Q if it doesn't work as opposed to asking for clarification on a documented method.

Comment: right, just wondering if anyone had done it before, let me attempt.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with jQuery if you have a lot of dinamyc scripting languages? Include is a common server side tag that helps you to achieve you want. PHP, Cold fusion, classic ASP, ASP.NET with controls or partials views, etc, allow you this behaviour.

Comment: This is actually a jsp included page. I was just making sure that the DOM did read it as part of the page, allowing me to utilize jquery to change the content displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work, assuming that when you inspect the DOM after including the file,

```
<html><body>some text <includedpage.html></body></html>
```

has become

```
<html><body>some text<div class="demo-container"></div></body></html>
```

jQuery operates on the current DOM structure of the page, including other changes that jQuery makes to it (such as inserting and removing elements, i.e. using `.html()` method), not the page as it was loaded from the server.