# How to reload / redirect page after successful login?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently using this in my controller right now: (new to angular don't beat me)

```
app.controller('userLogin', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', function ($scope, $http, $location, $route) {
    activeLink = 'userLogin';
    $scope.submitForm = function(valid) {
        if (valid) {
            $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            $http.post('/user/login', $('#userLoginForm').serialize())
            .success(function(data) {
                $route.reload();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Which works fine, when I reload the page the navbar login/create links disappear and is replaced with logout and what not, but my problem is the navbar doesn't reload unless I manually hit `CTRL+R`

I've tried using `$location.path('/');` and `$route.reload();` but my navbar doesn't change still unless I manually reload the page.

Comment: which state or route you want to navigate in your application after success?

Comment: you using ui-router or ngRoute?

Answer (score 2):

Would this do the trick? This should completely reload the page to the new address.

```
window.location.replace("/");
```

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

```
app.controller('userLogin', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', function ($scope, $http, $location, $route) {
    activeLink = 'userLogin';
    $scope.submitForm = function(valid) {
        if (valid) {
            $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            $http.post('/user/login', $('#userLoginForm').serialize())
            .success(function(data) {
                window.location.replace("/");
                //$route.reload();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

You could also try to hide the entire document, re-download the content of the document, and replace the content of current page.

```
$.get("/", function(data){
    $('body').html(data.body); // not sure if data.body will work, sort of guessing here
});
```

[jquery append external html file into my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page)

Replace the `BODY` tag to make styles stay in place.

[Replace entire HTML document in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825586/inplace-replace-entire-html-document)

Comment: It does for now, but surely there must be some way to do it without refreshing an entire page?

Comment: In theory, you could also try to hide the entire document, re-download the content of the document, and replace content of HTML tag, or document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page

Comment: @HelpNeeder i need to reload the page after redirecting to page. how to do it in ui-router. i have already tried $state.go('dashboard.places.list', {}, { reload: true}); it is redirecting to the particular view , but not reloads