# Why the "load" doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

index.html :

```
<div id="divTestArea2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#divTestArea2").load("index-2.html #test");

</script>
```

index-2.html :

```
<div id="test"><b>Hello World!</b></div>
```

Why the "load" doesn't work?

Comment: Do you receive a js error in your console. That would be helpful.

Comment: Do you test it locally?

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:61
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: Read this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypotheses:

1. `$` is not yet defined; your script may need to be run after jQuery is included in your page. You should see a console error if this is the case.
2. `index-2.html` is not a valid relative URL based on the current page's URL. Look at your developer tool's network tab to see if the request for `index-2.html` is being performed. If you're getting a 404 error, then maybe the URL isn't correct.

**Edit**

Now that you've posted the error, we know the cause is #1; `$` will only be defined if you're including jQuery in your page. If you already have that script tag, move your code to after that. If you don't, try adding something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery can already have been included but is using `noConflict` also as happens so often on wordpress sites

Comment: And the OP might need to enclose the script in a document ready handler.

Comment: @JayBlanchard if the script element appears after the referenced `div` then it will work.

Comment: That is why I said 'might' @JasonSperske. I have seen some cases where, even if all of the scripts were loaded prior to the closing body tag, none of the scripts worked without a document ready handler.

Comment: It's not a bad habit to get into (especially when learning JavaScript and jQuery in the beginning), it just has the (admittedly small) trade off of waiting longer than is necessary. However it sounds like you have experienced some deeper edge case where it became necessary, were you using a script loader like http://yepnopejs.com/ or http://requirejs.org/?

Comment: No @JasonSperske, neither of those were being used at the time but Modernizr may have been. I'll have to check if that was the case in each situation though.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add the `#` char to select the element by `id` and put your code inside the `ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#divTestArea2").load("index-2.html");

});
```

You could separate the div into another file to get only the necessary part instead trying to read a div inside the file.