# Wrap content with Header and Footer using LoadUrl in a WebView in Android

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, loaddata

I have a `header.html` file & a `footer.html` file in my `assets/html/` folder.

Here is my code to create and populate my `WebView` with content:

```
WebView contentView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentView);
String contentText = Function.OBJECT.get("info").toString();

contentView.loadData(contextText, "text/html", null);
```

How do I wrap `contextText` with the `header.html` and `footer.html` and present the output in the `WebView`?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you want to parse header.html and footer.html and put some content in between.

By using WebView.loaddata() you're telling the WebView to use a String as content, but that's not what you want.

It's easiert to make an index.html, add a header/footer div, bind/append the content from header.html/footer.html via Javascript/Jquery to those divs ([jquery append external html file into my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page)) and use WebView.loadUrl() to load your new index.html from the assets:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String url  =("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```