# How to read local html file in raw and add into textarea with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

How to read local html file in raw and add into textarea with jQuery 1.3?

Comment: show relevant codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $.get('local_file.html', function(data){
        $('textarea').val(data);
    });
});
```